# Why am I getting different results for the same exact query when I aggregate it in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have this query and I am trying to aggregate a certain field but when I use the same query in aggregation I dont get expected results

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "TEST",
            "fields": ["TESTFIELD1", "TESTFIELD2"],
            "lenient": true,
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "All": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "TESTAGG": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "TEST",
                    "fields": ["TESTFIELD1", "TESTFIELD2"],
                    "lenient": true,
                    "default_operator": "OR"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "subs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "TESTFIELD1",
                "size": 100,
                "order": { "_term": "asc" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is in the aggregation is that I get values for TESTFIELD1 that dont exist in the hits in the main query and I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some sample documents, and maybe the expected results ?

Comment: The main query did not specify a `size` so it defaults to 10, but the aggregation specifies a `size` of 100, so the aggregation returns more terms than the main query.

Comment: Thanks it was size!